# React/Alt - avoid dispatching within a dispatch when responding to user input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alt.js

I have a component that takes user input. When they save, I use an action to update a store's state

In response to this new information, a results component needs to run an async operation and then respond when new information comes back.

No matter what I try, I seem to be left with a hack `setTimeout` or a dispatch-within-dispatch error.

The async operation is defined via a datasource and has its own store as outlined [here](http://alt.js.org/docs/async/). What's the correct way to structure this behavior?

1. User input is received by input component.
2. Input component uses an action to update a store's state
3. Currently, the store attempts to start the async operation needed by the output component
4. My choice at this point seems to be Dispatch-with-dispatch error or a hack solution involving `setTimeout`. Neither feels correct.

What am I missing?

Comment: @JaromadaX So the flow I outlined is 100% how you would structure user input triggering both state change and further async behavior with react and altjs? 

I have a flow problem, not a code problem. I don't need code. I need program structure answers.

Comment: OK - I guess I've never seen "error or hacks" as part of a flow

Comment: @JaromandaX I'll update the question for those who didn't read the full intro text.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the examples about DataSources. Do not use `registerAsync` in stores.

Instead, use actions to perform async behavior and have results update stores. In the example you gave, do this from the input component:

```
Action1.updateStore()
AsyncAction2.run()
```

Then, use a store watching `AsyncAction2` actions to update and inform result components.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you want to be dispatching at that point and just want to avoid getting the "dispatch within a dispatch" error you can use alt's .defer method (see: http://alt.js.org/docs/actions/).